# ¿Como correr un cron job en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cronjobs

Desarrolle un pequeño modulo que básicamente envía un correo de felicitaciones a los usuarios en su cumpleaños, todo funciona bien pero ahora quisiera que este correo se enviara automáticamente todos los días a media noche, siguiendo un tutorial junto con la documentación de laravel cree un `comando` que me haga esta función, registre esto en el `kernel` pero ahora no estoy muy seguro de como seguir.

Según el tutorial que sigo me toca iniciar el `Laravel Scheduler` para que se ejecute el cron, segun es esta linea de codigo.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Pero no estoy muy seguro si esto lo ejecute en la consola del servidor donde esta alojado mi sistema. Es la primera vez que intento esto y no se muy bien como proseguir.

Este es mi archivo donde registro el comando:

```
class HappyBirthday extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'emails:birthday';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Envia un email de Cumpleaños a los usuarios';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $users = Employee::where('CONDICION', '=', 'A')->get();

        foreach($users as $user){

            $toDay    = Carbon::now('America/Caracas');
            $toDay    = $toDay->format('m-d');
            $dateUser = new Carbon($user->FECHA_NAC);
            $dateUser = $dateUser->format('m-d');

            if($toDay == $dateUser){

                Mail::to($user->EMAIL)->send(new Birthday($user));

            }

        }

        $this->info('Los mensajes de felicitacion han sido enviados correctamente');
    }

}
```

Y asi ejecuto el `schedule` desde mi `kernel.php`.

```
$schedule->command('emails:birthday')->daily()->timezone('America/Caracas');
```

¿Como debe proseguir para que mi comando se ejecute diariamente a media noche?

Answer (score 2):

Debes agregarlo al cron de tu panel de control,

```
0 0 * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
#    ^ ^ ^ Todos los dias 
#  ^ 0 Hora
#^ 0 Minutos
```